# Are there alternative keyboards for Windows 8 Modern-UI?

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-layout, modern-ui, on-screen-keyboard

On Android there are alternative keyboards available. For Windows 8 I couldn't find any such.

Specifically I'd like to have a keyboard that limits itself to the lower right edge of the screen in order to allow single-thumb-typing, as I do on my phone. This would also largely help on the desktop, where the programs don't work too well with half the screen hidden by a virtual keyboard.

To be fair, even for Android I cannot find THAT kind of keyboard<sup>1</sup>, so if anyone has an idea for Android - that would also be welcome.

Other alternative keyboards might also help, even if they add just such little things like numbers via press-and-hold of a letter (as used by many keyboards, including the iOS keyboard).

---

*<sup>1</sup> I've read swipe supports it for screens larger than 7", but first of all if I'd buy an Android tablet it would would be 7" and second I don't like auto-completion-suggestions, so swype isn't a viable option for me.*

Comment: You can find all of your choices in the Windows Store.

Comment: That doesn't really help though. Under the search term "keyboard" the closest match I find is piano keys. And even if I were to find any alternate keyboards, there would likely be countless offers nowhere the listed needs. I was really looking for a bit more specific pointers ;)

Comment: I guess you have your answer.  At this time there are no keyboard replacement Window Store applications.  I don't give product suggestions since that wouldn't be an on topic.